# What's the equivalent syntax of while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) for a "for loop"

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to know if it was possible to write the following expression

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

with a "for loop" instead of a "while loop."  So that the below code would print the same result.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

EDIT: I use PDO I just thought this would be an expression more people have seen.  And as far as the answers go, yeah I agree it would be pointless.  I'm just having trouble understanding how the internal pointer increments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be really pointless, but you could do:

```
for(;$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

However, you should seriously consider using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Answer (score 1):

```
for($row = NULL; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);;) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```